# 1996 Ford explorer XLT 5.0

Tags: ford, misfire, explorer

My explorer has what sounds like implosions or miss fire's in the intake when taking off and wants to stall and will stall when I come to a stop can anyone help. Some times runs rough some times runs very good.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you have a check engine light on? If so, have you read the codes?

Comment: Two things I would start checking : has the timing slipped? and do you have an air leak?

Comment: Are there any OB2 codes in the computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like the cam position sensor..the unit.. not just the cap...its a problem ford has had for some time...i just replaced one on my 2001 explorer...same problem as you have...bushings wear out

Comment: Thank you it was the camshaft synchronizer and sensor it broke in side the cap.

Comment: Glad i could help!